# Bootstrap modal won't show after it is triggered

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

Before I included display:none under modal-content in my css it worked fine but it was showing the modal window on the page before I clicked on it. However when I add it to my code, the modal-content window does not show anymore when I click on the div. I know it is because it isn't transitioning properly but can't figure out how to fix it. The screen darkens like it should but the window does not appear. I'll provide code for one of the boxes that I am working on, once I fix that I can fix the other 5.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section id="services" class="padding">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="icon_wrap text-center clearfix">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <a class="modal-invoker" href="#">
            <div class="icon_box border_radius">
            <i class="fa fa-icon-truck"></i>
            <h4 class="text-capitalize">Local Moving</h4>
            </div>
            <h4 class="item-title wow fadeInDown"> Local Moving</h4>
          <div class="modal-content">
             <p class="lead"><img src="images/moving.jpg" width="500" height="313" alt="moving"></p>
          </div>
          </a>
        </div>
```

The following is another part of my html code

```
 <div id="my-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Reservation</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <a href="tel:2017452424" class="btn btn-primary">견적의뢰</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

The following is the code in the css

```
.modal-content{
display:none;}
.modal-content img {
width: 100%;}
.item-title {
display:none;}
```

This is the javascript

```
$(document).on("click", ".modal-invoker", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var $container = $(this).parent();
$("#my-modal .modal-title").text($container.find(".item-title").text());
$("#my-modal .modal-body").html($container.find(".modal-content").html());
$("#my-modal").modal('show');
});

$(document).on("click", ".promotion-modal-invoker", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#my-modal .modal-title").text($(this).data("title"));
   $("#my-modal .modal-body").html($($(this).data("content")).html());
   $("#my-modal").modal('show');
});
```

Comment: you have `$("#myModal").modal()` in your JS?

Comment: yes I just showed it in my edit

Comment: Hi, you are adding `display:none;` to all `.modal-content`, that is why the modal you open won't show, because it also has the class `.modal-content`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are adding to the class `.modal-content` the css atribute `display: none;`. This is the cause of your modal not showing properly. Because the modal you open also contains the class `.modal-content`.

To fix this, just add the class `modal-reference` to

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <p class="lead"><img src="images/moving.jpg" width="500" height="313" alt="moving"></p>
</div>
```

So it looks like:

```
<div class="modal-content modal-reference">
    <p class="lead"><img src="images/moving.jpg" width="500" height="313" alt="moving"></p>
</div>
```

Add this class to your css (and remove `.modal-content` from it):

```
.modal-reference { /* new class */
    display:none;
}
.modal-content img {
    width: 100%;
}
.item-title {
    display:none;
}
```

With this modifications it should work the way you want it to. What we did was make the `display: none;` you added to all `.modal-content` to be only added on `.modal-reference`, so it does not affect the modal you are creating.

Best regards